# Android: WebViewClient onPageFinished/onReceivedError not called if internet goes after onPageStarted call

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I am displaying error message to user if webpage is not loaded, when there is no internet connection.

But the problem is: After onPageStarted method(here displaying progress dialog) is called, if I disconnect the internet by myself then onPageFinished/onReceivedError method is not called. As a result I am unable to display error message to user and not able to dismiss the dialog. The progress dialog keeps on displaying.

I was thinking that the WebView has a timeout which is handled by itself. But it's not. No time out happened. I waited for more than 15mins, but no tome out.

How could I handle this?

Comment: Well [onReceivedError](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) is the way to handle connection errors. Could you post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

there has two onReceivedError();

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {...}
```

this is only for `Android M+(API >=23);` if you device 's android api version < 23 this `onReceivedError()` can't be executed

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){...}
```

this method is for all android version;

`ps:errorCode` is not mean **http's** status code **(like 404 ,403),** you can see api doc